# Find value of a with given angle

Tags: geometry

The equations of the line $L$ and the plane $\Pi$ are as follows:

$$
L: \qquad x-5=-(y+1); z = 4
$$
$$
\Pi : \qquad \alpha x + z = 5\alpha +4
$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant.

If the angle between the line $L$ and $\Pi$ is $\pi/6$, what is the value of $\alpha$?

There are two answers, one positive and negative, but the answers I got is only  negative. Any help please. Thanking you guys in advanced :D

Comment: can you include your working?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh https://ibb.co/6t3PkD1 sorry the answer i got was a negative

Comment: please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) and type out your attempt in the question.

Comment: will do :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$L:\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -1 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}+ \lambda \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\frac{|\langle(1,-1,0),(\alpha, 0,1)\rangle|}{\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}=\cos\frac{\pi}6$$

$$\frac{|\alpha|}{\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}=\cos\frac{\pi}6$$

Hopefully you can solve for $\alpha$ to obtain one positive and one negative value of $\alpha$ from here.